# Are there any freely available plugins or integrations for JIRA to write test cases?

Tags: test-management, testcase, quality-assurance, jira

Are there any freely available plugins or integrations for **JIRA** to write test cases?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you searched for any plugins or integrations already? Why didn't they work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several paid options, such as Zephyr, Xray, and Test Management for JIRA. We use Zephyr at my company. All of these plugins have free trials available, but I'm not aware of any that are free.

I'd recommend browsing the Atlassian Marketplace and filtering by "test" and "free" to see if any of the plugins fit what you need:
https://marketplace.atlassian.com/search?moreFilters=free&query=test

Just be aware that some of the "free" plugins require an outside subscription to use.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen integration of [TestLink](http://testlink.org/) with Jira. There is even a [post](http://blogs.quovantis.com/step-by-step-integration-of-jira-with-testlink/) how to combine those two.

But I would really recommend paying for something like Zephyr or XRay. This thing above is madness.